Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{ \frac{m}{n}: m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, p \nmid n \}$, with the function $\delta$ is an Euclidean Domain.
In this exercise I need to prove that certain function over an Integral Domain, defines an Euclidean Domain.
The I.D. is defined as $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{ \frac{m}{n}: m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, p \nmid n \}$, where $p$ is a prime, and the function $\delta: \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}^{*} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+} \cup \{ 0 \}  $ is defined by:
$$ \delta(\frac{m}{n}) = p^q,$$ where $q$ is the maximum power of $p$ in $m$. This is, $m=p^q m'$ and $p\nmid m'$.
There are two things to prove: for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}^{*}$

$\delta(a) \leq \delta(ab)$
There exist $h,r \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ such that $b = ah+r$, where $r=0$ or $\delta(r) < \delta(a)$.

The proof of the first item was not difficult. However, I have been trying to prove the second item but I have not been able to.
I tried to mimic the proof for the Euclidean Domain $(F[x],\delta)$ for polynomials over a field $F$, where the function $\delta$ is the degree, and they use induction over the degree of $p(x)$, but I cannot conclude.
Is induction the way to go here?
Thanks for your help.

Let $b= \frac{m_1}{n_1}$ and $a=\frac{m_2}{n_2}$. Also, suppose that
$$m_1 = p^{q_1}x_1\quad \text{and}\quad m_2 = p^{q_2}x_2,$$
with $p\nmid x_1$ and $p\nmid x_2$.
$\textbf{Case 1.}$ Suppose $q_1 < q_2$. Then, simply take $h=0$ and $r=b$. We would have
$$b = ah+r,$$
with $\delta(r) = p^{q_1} < p^{q_2} = \delta(a)$.
$\textbf{Case 2.}$ Suppose $q_1 \geq q_2$. Then , observe that
$$h=\frac{p^{q_1-q_2}n_2x_1}{x_2n_1} \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}.$$
Clearly
$$b=ah,$$
for the above $h$. And here $r=0$.
